# php session not being deleted after setting its lifetime

Tags: php, session, cookies

I am a php newbie and practicing with php sessions. Basically, I have a login form which will be shown to a user ONLY if the session does not exist otherwise the page says "User Already Logged In".
I have set the session life time and cookie time using :

```
    session_set_cookie_params(60);
    ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 60);
```

I want the session to be destroyed after `1 minute` so that the user will have to log in again. but in my implementation, the session still exists for a long time and the users are logged in.

in my `login.php` i have:
1: if visited login.php with POST req, then check login credentials
2:if SESSION['logged_in'] is set then do not show the form, echo "already logged in"

```
<?php

require_once("helpers.php");

session_start();
if(!empty($_POST)){
    loginUser($_POST['user_id'], $_POST['pass']);
}

<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])){
    echo "<br>SESSION IS NOT SET UP";
    ?>

    <HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <LINK rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <SCRIPT src="test.js"></SCRIPT>
    </HEAD>
        <BODY>
            <H1>Please login</H1>
            <FORM action="login.php" method="post">
                <span class=formlabel>Username:</span>
                <INPUT  name="user_id" type="text" class="forminput" require><BR>
                <span class=formlabel>Password:</span>
                <INPUT  name="pass" type="password" class="forminput" require><BR>
                <INPUT type="submit" value="Login" style="width:80px;margin-left:100px;margin-top:3px;"><BR><BR>
                Don't have an account? <A href="register.php">Click here to register</A>.
            </FORM>
        </BODY>
    </HTML>
<?php
}else{
    echo '<strong>user already logged in.<br></strong>';
}
?>
```

Then in my `helper.php` I have a function:
1: check user id and password in data base
2: if it exists then set a session.

```
function loginCheck($user_id, $pass){
   //here goes code which checks if user_id & pass exists
   //store in $RESULT if exists
    if(!empty($result)){

        session_set_cookie_params(30, '/');
        ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 30);
        $_SESSION['username'] = $user_id;
        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
    }
}
```

Now when ever i log in as a user then the session starts and the login form dissapears, which is the correct behavior that i want. But the session never ends, i mean even if i refresh the page after 10 minutes the form doesn't show up and says "user already logged in".

also:
1: do the sessions gets destroyed by itself after their maxLifetime?
2: if not do we have to destroy it ?

thank you

Comment: You need to set the session parameters *before* you start the session.

Comment: @jeroen if i set the session parameters before the sessiont_start() does it gaurantee that the session will be destroyed and reset after that specified time period?

Answer (score 1):

The `gc_maxlifetime` value is the number of seconds after which data will be seen as garbage and **potentially** cleaned up.  You'll want to make sure this value is set high enough so that your sessions aren't destroyed too early, but you can't rely on sessions being destroyed after this amount of time.

If you want sessions destroyed after a specific period of time, then you should store a timestamp, and then use that timestamp and the presence of the session to see if the session is still alive.  Something like this:

```
$_SESSION['last_access'] = time();
```

Then later on, to check if it's still active:

```
if ( isset( $_SESSION['last_access'] ) && $_SESSION['last_access'] - 60 > time() ) {
    // The session is still alive
} else {
    // The session should be destroyed
    session_destroy();
    unset( $_SESSION );
}
```

Then, your future checks for the presence of any `$_SESSION` value will work the way you expect.

Comment: thanks. also, i have used session_start() in my login.php do i need to  do that in my helpers.php as well? and does refreshing the page reset the cookie and session lifetime?

Comment: I would put the code that creates the `last_access` index in your `helpers.php` file.  The other code would go wherever you wanted to validate the session. The session lifetime count is reset each time you call `session_start()`. If you want your session to live for 60 seconds since the last page access (so that reloading the page refreshes the session), then this is the desired behavior. Otherwise, you'd want to check for the existence of the `last_access` index before assigning it so that it doesn't get reset each load.